# Having an Issue with Typescript in VueJS with setProperty

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Still trying to get my head around typescript so please forgive me but my searches have yielded me no answers. All my other types have worked well but I just can't figure out how to get the value in style.setProperty(propertyName, value) to accept the number.

```
    function setRotation(vari: HTMLElement , rotationRatio: number) {
      vari.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotationRatio * 360);
    }
```

> Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | null

[image: TypeScript Error--']

Comment: looks like the error explains what is going on. You have a number, the function expects a string or null. Probably just need to convert the number to a string first. :) e.g (rotationRatio * 360).toString() or String(rotationRatio * 360). Whatever floats your boat for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value is expected to be as string.

It can be converted to a string, e.g.:

```
vari.style.setProperty('--rotation', `${rotationRatio * 360}`);
```

It's virtually always safe to provide numbers to native functions that expect strings, as they are coerced to strings internally. A type can be also casted, it takes a bit more characters in TS code and a bit less in compiled JS:

```
vari.style.setProperty('--rotation', (rotationRatio * 360) as unknown as string);
```